# Skype videocall upside down

Tags: skype, asus, webcam

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 64bit on an Asus k50fa. When I use the webcam on Skype the video is upside down and on cheese is working fine. The webcam is the one built in with the laptop.

Comment: http://www.ideasonboard.org/uvc/#footnote-3 "This camera module is known to be mounted upside-down in some notebooks. Applications that use the libv4l library should display the video correctly, as libv4l detects upside-down cameras and rotates the image automatically... ...For applications that don't use libv4l, try holding your computer upside-down."

Answer (score 7):

Fix for Skype Video upside Down.
My machine is an ASUS 64 bit running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, I got these commands from some one that posted it and I can't find his name now but it worked.
Go to terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libv4l-0:i386
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/skype.desktop
```

edit the `Exec=` line to make it look like this:

```
Exec=sh -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 skype %U'
```

Thats it. Run skype from the launcher by clicking it.

Note: if you run Skype from the terminal, or from the startup applications the web cam will still be upside down.
If you really need it to run it from the terminal, i recommend you to create an executable to preload the v4l1compat.so (to make the flip application and put it in `/bin/flip`)

Power PC down and bring back up then Skype will be fixed.
Your done./
Phil Thanks to the person I got this from just can't find his name at this time.

Comment: Yes, it was a good answer, but only until 2017. Since Skype 8 this trick will never work again.

Comment: I had to use an updated version of this line for ubuntu 18.04 on an asus laptop:
`Exec=sh -c 'LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so env PULSE_LATENCY_MSEC=60 /usr/bin/skypeforlinux %U'`

and it worked, thank you!

Comment: @yohann.martineau, works also on Kubuntu 20.04 with Skype 8.68

Answer (score 1):

Since, the Skype version 8 and above is basically a web app, the old trick with `libv4l` library will no longer work. I've lost many hours to just find out it's not possible anymore.

So since the software solution doesn't exist, I went towards a hardware one.
I've bought **an external web camera**... and it works flawlessly.
Moreover: I finally realized that built-in camera in Asus K-series laptops was of exceptionally low quality. My external one is sooo much better. Finally, after many years, my callers can see me clearly, and more importantly: correctly :-)

Comment: You need a correct file for the libv4l trick to work. Solution from this answer still works: https://askubuntu.com/a/991956/2509

Comment: Nope. Been there, done that. Trick with libv4l still doesn't work. It simply cannot, because newest Skype is a browser-based app.

Comment: @takeshin : you are right, it works fine!