# Skype for Linux on 64 bit Asus with upside down webcam

Tags: 64-bit, asus, skype, webcam

I just installed the most recent version of Skype for Linux, on a 64 bit Asus machine and the result is that the video image is upside down.
This does not happen with the Cheese app, where the video result is correct.

I already tried solving the problem following some solutions by installing the `libv4l-0:i386` package and launching the app by

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so skypeforlinux
```

and by

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so skypeforlinux
```

In both cases I get an error:

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.

ERROR: ld.so: object '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

And the app is launched without the preload, with the same obvious result.

Does anybody know how to solve this? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: The error: "wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32" means that you are trying to load sth. for the wrong bit system. (32/64 bit) Maybe this link helps: https://journalxtra.com/linux/skype-video-linux-always-hassle/

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of the Wrong ELF class try this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so /usr/bin/skype
```

or

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

I have to use now "skypeforlinux". I think I used "skype" before too.

If you install:

```
v4l2ucp
```

There is a setting: horizontal / vertical flip. This might solve your problem. Good luck.

Comment: I tried with both the commands but wasn't able to flip the video. When I run them, the webcam just does not activate, that is the screen is all black, but I don't get any errors in the terminal.

While by installing and running the 'v412ucp' package, when I check either vertical or horizontal flip, it does not work for Skype, but it does work when I run the webcam with 'cheese', that's so weird.

Comment: For me it works. Having the new Skype version 8 on 64 bit machine which binary has now name skypeforlinux.

Comment: This works for me too: kubuntu 18.04 x64, skype 8.28, asus K50ID.

Comment: Works for me. I just verified exact path before using it. In my case it's `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libv4l/v4l2convert.so`

Comment: It works fine with Skype-Version 8.34.0.78

Answer (score 0):

I have: E: "Unable to locate package v4l2ucp". I suppose the "E" stands for error. A new cam seems to be the solution.